# Is it possible to hide certain cells (not rows or columns) based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to hide certain cells based on a cell value.
I don't want the whole row or whole column to be hidden as I have other info on the row that needs to stay.

At a guess it's not possible, but worth an ask!

Already tried using basic excel buttons from the menus, but no luck.

[Image showing cells I want to be hidden (highlighted cells)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmCkC.png)

Answer (score 5):

No it is not possible to hide cells without hiding the entire column or row in which it is found.

You can use Conditional Formatting to make the cells appear blank by using the custom format of `;;;` which will show nothing in the cell but the formula bar will show the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the color of the font to match the color of the cell background.  The cell will "appear" empty.

However, the value will still appear in the Formula Bar if the cell is Active.  To prevent this display, just remove the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to hide individual cells like that, but you could color the cells in black if you're attempting to hide them from the user.